# Unable to connect MQTT broker with sim868

Tags: mqtt

did anyone use MQTT with sim868? My firmware is 1418B07SIM868M32_BT_TLS12. The only documentation I could find is SIM800 Series_MQTT_Application Note_V1.03.pdf but it is not helping

Comment: There isn't an answerable question here. Please read the [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on what a good question should contain

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it myself